# Bigquery nested table resulting out different results for similar queries

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, data-warehouse

I have Bigquery table with Record type *'trigger_prop'* column and here are two ways using which I am querying but it is resulting out different output:

**First Query:**

```
SELECT b.* FROM dataset.table a, unnest(trigger_prop) as b
where b.number=425600;
```

**Second Query:**

```
SELECT a.trigger_prop FROM dataset.table a, unnest(trigger_prop) as b
where b.number=425600;
```

*'Query1 is resulting out 1 record'*, while *'query2 is resulting out 2 records'* from table which are actual records. These both queries are doing same thing but resulting out different output. First query is returning less record while second query is returning actual records. Can someone please help me in understanding the difference in both queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not doing the same thing, the difference is the SELECT **a**.trigger_prop vs SELECT **b**.* which are different tables.
The first query selects the unnested translation of `trigger_prop`from table b which "unfolds" the array and keeps the single array item with `number=425600`.
The second query selects the raw `trigger_prop` field from the source table and returns a single row, **but** this row has multiple array items in it so it *looks* like multiple rows because of the array in `trigger_prop`.

To demonstrate I ran the following query, note the `LIMIT 1` clause:

```
WITH
  TABLE AS (
  SELECT
    ARRAY<STRUCT<number INTEGER,
    name STRING>>[(1,
      "me"),
    (2,
      "you")] AS trigger_prop)
SELECT
  a.trigger_prop
FROM
  TABLE AS a,
  UNNEST(trigger_prop) AS b
WHERE
  b.number=1
LIMIT 1
```

This gives the following result, note how it's a single row which *looks* like multiple rows.
[image]

Comment: thanks for the response. But can you explain why it is the case, that unnest is returning less record while directly accessing the trigger_prop column resulting out more records which is actually true?

Comment: I realised I got the row counts the wrong way around in my answer so I'll fix that. The  general answer is still the same though - you're getting different answers because you're asking different questions, those queries are **not** doing the same thing. Can you post anonomised versions of the results of the queries and that might help explain?

Comment: I've updated the answer with an example which I hope will make things clearer.

Comment: thanks. That's what I was looking for. It really clears my doubt between the following queries. Putting limit condition at end and still this query is resulting out same result.